# At the end of Star Trek Beyond, how did Uhura know who Krall was?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-trek, star-trek-beyond

At the end of *Star Trek Beyond*, how did Uhura know that

> Krall was Captain Edison?
>  I saw she slowed down some video of what looked like people celebrating (not sure why THAT video stood out to her) and somehow deduced from watching something in slow-motion that Krall was Edison.

I didn't catch what was so significant from that video that it caught her attention.  I might need to watch a second time (or multiple times on DVD when it comes out) to see what was significant in that video.

Comment: She noticed that the actor was Idris Elba and that there was no way that such a notable actor would be in the movie without being a significant character.

Comment: @sanpaco That's a really good guess. XD (upvote)

Comment: @sanpaco explain Thor 2 or AoU

Comment: @cde foreshadow

Comment: @cde Heimdall is a major character.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Lt. Nyota Uhura is a communications specialist, with a talent for languages by ear. This extended to her analysis of Krall, as she is the only one he speaks to at length aside from Kirk. Specifically:

> The Federation has pushed ***the frontier*** for centuries.
> But now enough.
> This is where it begins, Lieutenant.
> This is where **the frontier**, pushes back.

And in the video log when Uhura analysis it, there is a bit where Edison, back towards the camera, says:

> ...expand the frontier...
> *rewind*
> ...expand **the frontier**...
> *rewind, slow down*
> ...expand ***the frontier***...

Nyota plays back the video multiple times, slowing it down.

She also sees first hand Krall absorbing the life forces of two human crew members, and his skin and voice changing accordingly. Both become less bumpy, grungy, more smooth, more human.

#### Between changing the pitch of the Video, and Krall's changing voice, and the specific keyword of Frontier, it clicked in her head.

She still didn't know exactly how or why, but she ***knew*** Krall is Edison from watching the video. Right after the rewinds:

> Uhura: It's him. Scotty, I need you to link to Franklin database.
> Find out what you can about Balthazar Edison.
> Scott: What?! The Captain of the Franklin?
> Uhura: Yes.
> Scott: He is long dead.
> Uhura: ***No he is not. I do not know how, but Edison is Krall.***

Comment: Thx.  I guess I need a hearing aid or something.  i didn't catch that when watching.  How many times did you watch it to memorize the dialogue or did you find it somewhere else on the web?

Comment: @Classified once. But the exact dialog came from a subtitle file.

Comment: I finally heard it on my third viewing....  Know that I know it's there, it's clear as day....

Answer (score 11):

Actually, I thought she recognized his voice.  *(remember - great communications officer, knows three dialects of Romulan, ...)*

Comment: oh, that might be a possible explanation, although, she slowed down the video so the voice would be distorted.

Comment: @Classified Edison ' s voice became more distorted as he became Krall, and the opposite was true. She heard him as his physical shape and voice started changing.

Comment: It's definitely this. She said something about his voice.

Comment: @Classified The slowing down is what helped her recognize the two voices were the same.

Comment: And yet despite knowing three dialects of Romulan, she has to pull out a Klingon-phrase book when the universal translator is down. Or maybe Old Spock told this timeline's version of Uhura to brush up on her Klingon to avoid such embarrassing situations in the future.

Comment: @Thunderforge Well, the Beyond Timeline is much more militaristic, so it stands to reason that maybe Beyond Timeline Uhura studied a bit harder on her translations.

Comment: She knew Vulcan because of her Vulcan boyfriend. Romulan is a variation of old Vulcan.

Answer (score 7):

As shown in the film, as Krall absorbs life force from others his appearance changes, most notably his skin appears to become smoother, and later in the film he was able to absorb enough life force to almost completely regain his human appearance. Having conversed with Krall in person and seeing him use his abilities, it's possible that even a glance at the rescue footage the USS Franklin had in its databanks was enough for her to postulate that maybe Captain Edison may be Krall.

After the idea comes to her and Kirk upon closer examination of the video they initially found, they find Edison's logs and learn of his ultimate fate. This could be corroborated with the fact that he seems to have very intimate knowledge of the Federation itself, and even mentions to Uhura that his ultimate goal is to destroy the Federation.

Answer (score 4):

I watched the film a little more than a week ago, and I've hardly an eidetic memory, but I got the strong impression that it was a specific *phrase* that Krall had told Uhura, which she then overheard in the background of a video. I cannot recall the phrase itself, but I'm pretty sure it was hearing this phrase and isolating its source that led to identifying Krall as Edison.

Comment: "Frontier". The final clue.

Comment: Indeed, that's it, as spelled out in your own answer. Thanks!